# Python Pandas: differences between two dates in weeks?

Tags: python, pandas

When trying to find differences between two dates in weeks:

```
import pandas as pd

def diff(start, end):
    x = millis(end) - millis(start)
    return x / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 7 * 1000)

def millis(s):
    return pd.to_datetime(s).to_datetime64()

diff("2013-06-10","2013-06-16")
```

As a result I get:

```
Out[15]: numpy.timedelta64(857,'ns')
```

Which is obviously wrong. Questions:

1. How to get the difference in weeks, not nanoseconds, rounded up to a whole value?
2. How to get value out of 'numpy.timedelta64' object?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I think you can convert to `int` by dividing by numpy scalar:

```
def diff(start, end):
    x = pd.to_datetime(end) - pd.to_datetime(start)
    return int(x / np.timedelta64(1, 'W'))

print (diff("2013-06-10","2013-06-16"))
0
print (diff("2013-06-10","2013-06-26"))
2
```

See [frequency conversion](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timedeltas.html#frequency-conversion).

Answer (score 2):

You can use `pandas.Timedelta` as well:

```
import pandas as pd

def diff(start, end):
    days = pd.to_datetime(end) - pd.to_datetime(start)
    week = int(pd.Timedelta(days).days / 7)
    remainder = pd.Timedelta(days).days % 7
    return str(week) + ' weeks and ' + str(remainder) + ' days'

print(diff("2019-06-10","2019-07-11"))

Output:
4 weeks and 3 days
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple fix:

```
def diff(start, end):
    x = millis(end) - millis(start)
    return np.ceil(x.astype(int) / (7*86400*1e9))
```

The main thing is to remove the units (nanoseconds) before operating on it.

P.S.: Consider not calling your function `millis()` when it does not return milliseconds.

Answer (score 0):

jezrael's answer threw an error for me so here's an alternate solution (in case you also got an error when trying it)

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
def diff(start, end):
    x = pd.to_datetime(end) - pd.to_datetime(start)
    return (x).apply(lambda x: x/np.timedelta64(1,'W')).astype(int)
```

Comment: Which library is np?

Comment: @carduque it is `import numpy as np`