# How do I specify certain date as the first week and calculate the week number in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

[how to convert time to week number](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FL9ZN.png)

year_start = '2019-05-21'

year_end = '2020-02-22'

How do I get the week number based on the date that I set as first week?
For example 2019-05-21 should be Week 1 instead of 2019-01-01

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I think this question [has already been asked and answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41311990/python-pandas-differences-between-two-dates-in-weeks). Or are you asking for something different?

Comment: In your original format, how should '2019-02-27' or '2020-06-23' be described?

Comment: @quasi-human Week 1 is 2019-05-21 to 2019-05-26 and subsequently count the rest of the weeks

Comment: So it it alright to suppose the date range is between `year_start` and `year_end`. In other words, I want to know whether I don't need to deel with '2019-02-27' or '2020-06-23' for example.

Comment: I think Week 1 is 2019-05-21 to 2019-05-27, not 2019-05-21 to 2019-05-26. Is it correct?

Comment: yes the date range is between year_start and year_end. Week 1 is till 2019-05-26 as a new week should start on Monday

Comment: You should use the builtin date methods ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71182907/16343464))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following code.

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

year_start = '2019-05-21'
year_end = '2020-02-22'

# Create a sample dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(pd.date_range(year_start, year_end, freq='D'), columns=['date'])

# Add the week number
df['week_number'] = (((df.date.view(np.int64) - pd.to_datetime([year_start]).view(np.int64)) / (1e9 * 60 * 60 * 24) - df.date.dt.day_of_week + 7) // 7 + 1).astype(np.int64)
```

| date | week_number |
| --- | --- |
| 2019-05-21 | 1 |
| 2019-05-22 | 1 |
| 2019-05-23 | 1 |
| 2019-05-24 | 1 |
| 2019-05-25 | 1 |
| 2019-05-26 | 1 |
| 2019-05-27 | 2 |
| 2019-05-28 | 2 |
|  |  |
| 2020-02-18 | 40 |
| 2020-02-19 | 40 |
| 2020-02-20 | 40 |
| 2020-02-21 | 40 |
| 2020-02-22 | 40 |

Comment: I'll try to come up with shorter way to do this.

Comment: Good luck with your project:)

Answer (score 1):

If you do not have dates outside of year_start/year_end, use `isocalendar().week` and perform a simple subtraction with modulo:

```
year_start = pd.to_datetime('2019-05-21')
#year_end = pd.to_datetime('2020-02-22')

df = pd.DataFrame({'date': pd.date_range('2019-05-21', '2020-02-22', freq='30D')})

df['week'] = (df['date'].dt.isocalendar().week.astype(int)-year_start.isocalendar()[1])%52+1
```

Output:

```
        date  week
0 2019-05-21     1
1 2019-06-20     5
2 2019-07-20     9
3 2019-08-19    14
4 2019-09-18    18
5 2019-10-18    22
6 2019-11-17    26
7 2019-12-17    31
8 2020-01-16    35
9 2020-02-15    39
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing a nice technique. I didn't come up with this way. Upvoted.

Comment: @papooties, Hey, use this `isocalendar().week` method because it's a more concise way than mine.

Answer (score 0):

If you just need a function to calculate week no, based on given start and end date:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

start_date = "2019-05-21"
end_date = "2020-02-22"
start_datetime = pd.to_datetime(start_date)
end_datetime = pd.to_datetime(end_date)

def get_week_no(date):
    given_datetime = pd.to_datetime(date)
    # if date in range
    if start_datetime <= given_datetime <= end_datetime:
        x =  given_datetime - start_datetime
        # adding 1 as it will return 0 for 1st week
        return int(x / np.timedelta64(1, 'W')) + 1
    raise ValueError(f"Date is not in range {start_date} - {end_date}")

print(get_week_no("2019-05-21"))
```

In the function, we are calculating week no by finding difference between given date and start date in weeks.